# Looking for a spreadsheet (or table) view for django

Tags: django, spreadsheet

Pardon the dumb question, but where can I find a view for Django to display "tables" in a spreadsheet-like format (i.e. one record per row, one field per column).

(The fact that I have not been able to find one after some searching tells me that maybe my noob-level understanding of Django views is way off-base.)

Here I'm intending the term "table" fairly generically; basically, think of a table as an "list of lists", with the additional constraint that all the internal lists have the same length.

(It would be great if this table had spreadsheet features, such as the possibility of sorting the rows by clicking on the column headers, or of cutting and pasting arbitrary rectangular subsets of the cells, but I realize that this may be hoping for too much.)

Comment: Django doesn't do that kind of frontend stuff automatically.
If you're referring to the Django admin, it can do it in a limited way: http://is.gd/MgufEW .
Either way, rendering a table should be very straight-forward using Django's template language.

Comment: Have you checked out Django's class-based view `ListView`? It's not everything you are looking for but it may be of interest.

Comment: Also the [django-tables2](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/django-tables2) package (not part of of Django itself) may be interesting to you. Haven't used it myself.

Answer (score 0):

An other way to do it is to use tabular inlines but a list view is what you are looking for.